# What does custom mean when it comes to parties?

Tags: american-english, errors

I've seen different sets of people from around the country mention a "custom party" on *written* Halloween invitations. Does it simply mean costume (and just intentionally mis-spelled)? Or some specific kind of costume?

Comment: Is it on invitations, or more in the party planning context?

Comment: It's on invitations.

Comment: @simchona I bet you are right, because I cannot imagine a “bespoke” Halloween party.  I mean, aren’t they all such?

Comment: 27th rule of the Internet: People Can't Spell.

Comment: @MarkBeadles If they did it once, I would pass it off as typo/misspelling, but they consistently keep on doing it...

Comment: The only answer that I can really give is...it does not mean costume party, and it is not a specific kind of costume.

Comment: Doing a Google search for "custom party" I get lots of hits for custom party planners but nothing that suggests that *custom party* has any specific meaning.  I believe you when you say it's not a typo, but I have to believe it's a misspelling or perhaps a helpful spelling "correction" by Word.

Comment: I'd like to see some examples of this consistent spelling, otherwise this is Too Localized.

Comment: Google "invited to a custom party" and "going to a custom" party and you will find hits like [this one](http://www.flickr.com/photos/crowchick/45878113/) (fourth post, among others which spell the word correctly) which make it clear that some English speakers, including native speakers, don't hear a difference between *custom* and *costume*, and carry this over into writing.

Comment: @test: Misspelling is about written English; mispronunciation is about spoken English. Usually, people pronounce it correctly and misspell it, but in this case, they've done both. First rule of success in the flimflam business of Business: "There's no underestimating the intelligence of the American public", H. L. Mencken. When people can't do better than spell "lose" as "loose" and the contraction "would've" as "would of", how can you expect anything better from people who cannot discriminate between "costume" and "custom"? The **custom** on Halloween is to have a **costume** party.

Comment: @StoneyB That link doesn't indicate anything other than the commenter didn't know how to spell costume...everyone else on that post spelled it correctly. This seems to just be a misspelling, and I haven't seen anything to indicate it's not.

Comment: @StoneyB: That post also says that her brother's going as **the Crow**, from which I infer that she's not a native speaker of English.

Comment: "Custom" also means "business patronage", so perhaps the invitation was to a **Tupperware Party**. My mother used to throw those all the time when I was a kid.

Comment: @BillFranke  Sure, about half of the misspellings I found were non-native, and it's an acknowledged [problem](http://sitzmanabc.blogspot.com/2012/02/false-friend-costumbre-vs-custom-and.html) among ESL teachers. But both native and non-native speakers misspell, and I suggest this is because **a)** there is phonetic confusion (at least in the U.S., where we often do not palatalize the 'tu'), and **b)** there is also semantic overlap: see the entries for [custom](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=custom) at Urban Dictionary , especially the first citation.

Comment: @StoneyB: "You can't polish a turd, but you can spray paint it gold, and call it custom." I like that one. But this is probably what you meant: "1. A well thought out, and designed project using the finest parts, and workmanship." I agree with your points.

Comment: @BillFranke  Actually, the spray paint one was my point--that's the overlap with "costume". And after all, should it surprise us that having begun as one word these two should return to their primitive identity? Perhaps these apparent illiterates are in fact sensitive scholars of etymology.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, it just goes to prove what I can miss when I don't think about what I read. You're quite right about the spray paint quote.

Comment: @StoneyB You say some people pronounce _custom_ and _costume_ the same, but could you give some indication of how they pronounce it then? It's difficult for me to imagine a sound that could mean both.

Comment: @MrLister My conjecture (and it's no more than that) is that what's involved is an idiolectal variant of *costume* governed by a trochaic rather than the standard spondaic prosody, so the (unpalatalized) **u:** in the second syllable is reduced to **ə**. In this context confusion between **ɒ** and **ʌ** is easy to imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will have gathered from comments- the writer of the invitation cannot spell, and means 'costume party'

You can use custom to mean bespoke, but you would need context for it to mean anything here.